# Execute a function differently depending on when it was first run

Tags: javascript

I want a piece of code to execute only if run within a 6 seconds period after the first time it is run.

I was thinking about doing this like so:

```
var withinSix = false;
function onDeleteKeyUp(){
    withinSix = true;
    if(withinSix){
        //interaction code here
        setTimeout(function(){
            withinSix = false;
        }, 6000);
     }
});
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Alternatively, without using an timers, just track when it is first called:

```
var called = -1;

function onDeleteKeyUp(){

    // Track the current time on the first call. (in ms)
    if (called === -1){
        called = (new Date()).getTime();
    }

    // Compare the current time to the time of the first call. (6s = 6000ms)
    if ((new Date()).getTime() - called < 6000){
        // Within 6 seconds...

    } else {
        // After 6 seconds...

    }
}
```

Comment: +1 I like this solution better cause actually is even kinder in the confronts of a browser. I won't take resources unnecessary by running a timeout in the background.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can start a timer when the page loads and then do something after six seconds:

```
var withinSix = true;   // By default, the click happened within six seconds
setTimeout(function() { // Start a timer that will fire after six seconds
    withinSix = false;  // The timer fired, clear the flag
}, 6000);               // 6000ms = 6 seconds
function onDeleteKeyUp(){
    if(withinSix){      // Was it before the timer fired?
        // Yes, it happened within 6 seconds of when this code started
    }
});
```

Now, when you *start* the timer is up to you. The above code starts it immediately when the code is run. This would be most appropriate if the code is in a `script` element at the very *end* of the `body` (just before the closing `</body>` tag), which is best practice. But you'll want to start the timer whenever is appropriate to your use case.